# why can add parameter type and return type to javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm learning react native. When I see XMLHttpRequest Base.js, I wonder why is the grammar so strange? I have never seen this before. Please help.

```js
class XMLHttpRequestBase {
 UNSENT: number;
  onload: ?Function;
  responseHeaders: ?Object;
  upload: ?{
    onprogress?: (event: Object) => void;
  };
  constructor() {
  }
  _didUploadProgress(requestId: number, progress: number, total: number): void {
    if (requestId === this._requestId && this.upload && this.upload.onprogress) {
      var event = {
        lengthComputable: true,
        loaded: progress,
        total,
      };
      this.upload.onprogress(event);
    }
  }
}
```

[Link to the file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequestBase.js).

Comment: what you want to achive ? be specific

Comment: Only learn, want to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have parameters types or return types. Nothing has changed here. However, facebook developed [Flow](http://flowtype.org/) library which is *''a static type checker, designed to find type errors in JavaScript programs:''* And it allows to do things like in your example.

The [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) page even says that Flow is one of the prerequisites that must be downloaded and installed in order to use react-native.